# Trying to automate taking screenshot on Reddit and facing issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to make the python work from the Youtube video that I watched: Making Automatic YouTube videos with Python and got the reference from there.
I am having trouble to troubleshoot the error. The author already archived the issues that was discussed a few months ago. I created a new folder called Screenshots so the python bot can save it. Now I have no idea what to do.

[image]

[image]

I have tried to add a new folder and increase the wait seconds from 10 to 20 seconds.

increase wait time to generate screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
#prelim
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
o = Options()
o.page_load_strategy = ['none', 'normal', 'eager'][1]
##use *normal* for implicit (this should be default anyways)
d = webdriver.Chrome(options = o)  #deprecated - services best practice



#(1) not most efficient way - use:
d.implictly_wait(30)
d.get('https://www.google.com')

#for screenshot
d.save_screenshot('Folder_Path/screenshot_1.png')
## no arguments i.e () to save to same folder as script - ta    

#(2)explicit wait (remove implicitly_wait above)
d.get('https://www.google.com')
try: WebDriverWait(d,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'ID_HERE')))
except: print('not found')
#put relevant AND unique ID (not present on pvs site) in place of *ID_HERE*
d.save_screenshot('Folder_Path/screenshot_2.png')
```

---

Notes:
customize as req.

This gives two methods - implicitly_wait (which is default in absence of any other method, but setting it allows user-defined seconds as parameter -- and an explicit wait as an alternative (using expected conditions) - many say not to use both methods in combination but I don't experience any issues in doing so -the implicitly wait will wait until the page is loaded (s.t. max seconds) then the explicit method will kick in (they cannot and will not work in tandem as far as I can tell).

Trouble-shooting may involve ensuring you have selected an appropriate element to wait for if using the explicit method.

Can also put in `EC.url_changes` or `EC.url_to_be` etc. as a first explicit wait condition followed by the one above if you find common element IDs from one page to next.